# Android Content Provider; Help designing respectable URI structure

Tags: android, rest, uri, android-contentprovider

I'm designing an android app and would like to use a Content Provider to populate my list views. Problem is I need data from from two different sources (tables in the database): One set of static data, and another for user progress data related to the the static data.

So for example, I got a list of quizzes, and a list of grades for a user for each of these quizzes.

If SimpleCursorArray took two cursors then I could use:

```
/quizzes  
/users/#/quiz_grades
```

as the two URI's and pass the cursors to the Adapter.

But SimpleCursorArray can only take one cursor so I need to join the two tables I have. No problem, but how do I design a *clean* URI?

Maybe something like:

```
/users/#/quizzes
```

But this doesn't feel right because the questions don't belong to users...

Or maybe:

```
/quizzes/users/#
```

But again, users don't belong to questions...

Plus sometimes I need to retrieve a quiz on its own without the user grade so I also need:

```
/quizzes/#
```

I know this is a very pedantic question, but my OCD nature won't let me progress with any satisfaction until I figure this out...

Comment: Since you only have two tables, posting the DDL might help us get a better understanding of how they're related. That said, if the only reason for your content provider is to pass data *within* your application, then it's overkill. Why not just access the tables directly?

Comment: I have more than two tables, but in this example I'm only making use of two tables (views actually). The QuizSummary view has the columns _id, name, num_questions and the QuizProgress view has the columns user_id, quiz_id, num_questions_correct. So in my list view, I populate a TextView with the quiz name, and a progress bar with num_questions_correct out of num_questions.

Comment: I currently have it implemented as a direct table access, but this blocks the UI and slows down a app a bit. I'd like to make user of SimpleCursorAdapter and that led me down the road to ContentProvider. I do agree it might be overkill, so I'm second guessing this idea. If it makes any difference, I'm eventually planning on having this data being sent back and forth from a server.

Answer (score 0):

How about `/users/#/quizzes-with-grades`?